# Table join when no matches then use a defined string

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to join one table to another, however when there are no matches I'd like to use a specific string value to match on instead where I know there will be matching values.

For example, take this structure

```
declare @A table (id int identity(1,1), category varchar(4))
declare @B table (category varchar(4), name varchar(10))

insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AC')
insert @A values ('AD')

insert @B values ('AB', 'Fred')
insert @B values ('AC', 'Bob')
insert @B values ('else', 'Jane')
insert @B values ('else', 'Mary')
```

If I used a simple join:

```
select a.id, a.category, b.category, b.name
from @A a 
inner join @B b on a.category = b.category
```

Then the first 5 records would match and I'd end up with:

```
1   AB  AB  Fred
2   AB  AB  Fred
3   AB  AB  Fred
4   AB  AB  Fred
5   AC  AC  Bob
```

However, what I'd like to do is for that the last record which didn't have a matching record I'd like to replace the category "AD" in table @A with "else" so that it matched the two records in table @B and came back as:

```
1   AB      AB      Fred
2   AB      AB      Fred
3   AB      AB      Fred
4   AB      AB      Fred
5   AC      AC      Bob
6   else    else    Jane
6   else    else    Mary
```

**UPDATE:**

There may also be occasions where table @A doesn't contain matching records so I don't think a RIGHT JOIN can be used as I don't want all records from @B. For example, if @A didn't have the "AC" record and just contained:

```
insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AD')
```

Then the output would be:

```
1   AB      AB      Fred
2   AB      AB      Fred
3   AB      AB      Fred
4   AB      AB      Fred
5   AB      AB      Fred
6   else    else    Jane
6   else    else    Mary
```

What would the various options be to return the correct data?

Comment: Why not `RIGHT JOIN` your `B` table and then use a `ISNULL()` in your `SELECT` statement to display the 'else'.  I'm not quite sure what you're looking to do here.  You could also use two join conditions with an `OR` subquery in your join statement like `JOIN ON category = category OR IF NOT EXISTS ...`

Comment: I don't think I can right join as I don't want all records from @B (see update)

Comment: So, do you want it to return everything from B that matches A plus everything in B that has 'else'?  How does Bob get returned with "AB"?

Comment: @ca8msm I'm just a little confused about what you're trying to achieve.  In your original question you say "however when there are no matches I'd like to use a specific string value to match on instead where I know there will be matching values".  What does this mean?  If it doesn't have a match, then it should be matched to the "else" right?  In your update you say "There may also be occasions where table @A doesn't contain matching records", you already said this, and you said in that case to use the `else` string match...  Can you explain what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Sorry it's my explanation and updated results that confused matters! I just want everything from A and where there is no match in B then to use the "else" records.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a RIGHT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.  This would give you all the rows in Table B.

Then, I would change your query parameters to use "b.category" instead of "a.category", as it won't always have a match.

Finally, you can use ISNULL() for when there is no match for the ID.

```
select a.id, ISNULL(a.category, b.category), b.category, b.name
from @A a 
    RIGHT join @B b on a.category = b.category
```

Your a.ID will still be null, though.  If you're wanting to have one more than the max value of id in table A, you could do that as well.

```
select ISNULL(a.id, (SELECT MAX(id) from @a)), ISNULL(a.category, b.category), b.category, b.name
from @A a 
    RIGHT join @B b on a.category = b.category
```

So, if in your update, you mean to have only rows from B that EITHER have a matching row in A OR have "else" as the category, then you could do this:

```
select ISNULL(a.id, (SELECT MAX(id) from @a)), ISNULL(a.category, 
b.category), b.category, b.name
from @A a 
    RIGHT join @B b on a.category = b.category
where a.id is not null or b.category = 'else'
```

But I don't understand how you get "Bob" with "AB" as his category.

Results:

```
1   AB      AB      Fred
2   AB      AB      Fred
3   AB      AB      Fred
4   AB      AB      Fred
5   else    else    Jane
5   else    else    Mary
```

Comment: Thanks, that produces the correct results that I asked for, however I don't think I can right join as I don't want all records from @B (see my update to the original question)

Comment: Then you need to give an example where my solution will not work.  Otherwise, I don't understand what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for `Right Join` as you want to populate table @B in all scenario.

```
select a.id, ISNULL(a.category,b.category) category, b.category, b.name
from @A a 
right join @B b on a.category = b.category
```

output :

```
id          category category name
----------- -------- -------- ----------
1           AB       AB       Fred
2           AB       AB       Fred
3           AB       AB       Fred
4           AB       AB       Fred
5           AC       AC       Bob
NULL        else     else     Jane
NULL        else     else     Mary
```

Comment: This doesn't return the correct results as the id with 6 is missing

Answer (score 0):

You have to join @B twice. First time "normally" and then when b1 is null and b2.category not already joined in the "normal" join. Like this:

```
declare @A table (id int identity(1,1), category varchar(4))
declare @B table (category varchar(4), name varchar(10))

insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AB')
insert @A values ('AC')
insert @A values ('AD')

insert @B values ('AB', 'Fred')
insert @B values ('AC', 'Bob')
insert @B values ('else', 'Jane')
insert @B values ('else', 'Mary')


select
    a.id
    , coalesce(b2.category, a.category) as category1
    , coalesce(b2.category, b1.category) as category2
    , coalesce(b2.name, b1.name) as name
from @A a
    left join @b b1 on a.category = b1.category
    left join @b b2 on b1.category is null and b2.category not in (select
                                                                    a.category
                                                                from @A a
                                                                    inner join @B b on a.category = b.category)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to also have the id, I recommend this solution:

```
select a.id, a.category, b.category, b.name
from @A a 
inner join @B b on a.category = b.category
union all
select nomatch.id, b.category, b.category, b.name
from (select a.id
   from @A a 
   left join @B b on a.category = b.category
   where b.category is null ) nomatch
join @b  
where b.category = 'else'
```

I'm not completely sure about the syntax but that would be the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @A table (id int identity(1,1), category varchar(4))  
    declare @B table (category varchar(4), name varchar(10))  
    Declare @id int = 0  **--added line**  
    insert @A values ('AB')  
    insert @A values ('AB')  
    insert @A values ('AB')  
    insert @A values ('AB')  

insert @A values ('AC')  
insert @A values ('AD')  
SELECT @id = @@IDENTITY; **----added line**  
insert @B values ('AB', 'Fred')  
insert @B values ('AC', 'Bob')  
insert @B values ('else', 'Jane')  
insert @B values ('else', 'Mary')  

select  a.category, b.category, b.name,  
case   
when a.ID IS not NULL then a.id   
else  @id   
end as ID  
from @A a   
right join @B b on a.category = b.category
```